# Drupal Block Title Span Around Every Word

Tags: php, html, css, drupal

Looking to add a span tag around every word in the block title. I need to have the last two words in my title be a larger font, and also a different color.

Comment: Post some code. Hard to help when you haven't shown what you have tried. A span tag is... <span>text</span> so add those tags around the words in your title.

Answer (score 1):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block = $variables['block'];
  if ($block->subject) {
    $words = explode(' ', $block->subject);
      $words[0] = '<span>' . $words[0] . '</span>';
      $words[0] = '<span>' . $words[0] . '</span>';
      $words[1] = '<span>' . $words[1] . '</span>';
      $words[2] = '<span>' . $words[2] . '</span>';
      $words[3] = '<span>' . $words[3] . '</span>';
      $words[4] = '<span>' . $words[4] . '</span>';
    $block->subject = implode(' ', $words);
  }
}
```

Figured it out inside template.php for my issue,but there is probably a prettier implementation with using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop for ThroneDigital's answer:

```
$newWords = array();
foreach(explode(' ', $block->subject) as $word) {
    $newWords[] = '<span>' . $word . '</span>';
}
$block->subject = implode(' ', $newWords);
```

You could also use the array_map() function, but that requires you to create a new function, and for such a small bit of text it's not worth it.